# Link a method from a controller to a button click in Spring boot Java

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on a spring java project. I have a view that contains multiple buttons. Each one will fire a method from the controller. So how can I link my button click function to a specific method in my controller?

Here is some of the HTML from the MainView.html

```
 <button class="btn btn-success btn-default">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 </button>
```

Here is the MainController class:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;


@Controller
public class MainController
{

    @GetMapping(value="/")
    public String home() 
    {
         return "views/MainView";
    }

     public void run() //I want to link the button click to this method
     {  
         System.out.println("Test1");
         System.out.println("Test2");
         System.out.println("Test3");
         System.out.println("Test4");
     }
}
```

Comment: your web frontend needs to perform a GET request to your controller. Is this going to be a single page app style webapp (then you would use some library to submit an ajax request for you) or a traditional request/response webapp (in which case you could have an HTML form that submits to your Controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a mapping to your method and call that from a js function. I'm not sure what your goal is.
On your controller:

```
@GetMapping(value="/run")
public void run() //I want to link the button click to this method
     {  
         System.out.println("Test1");
         System.out.println("Test2");
         System.out.println("Test3");
         System.out.println("Test4");
     }
```

Then your button can just call a javascript function to get data from */run*

Comment: Can you explain how a javascript function will call my java method?

Comment: Depending on what you want the run method to do, you could do an AJAX call, send data to the method if you need to.

Comment: Here's a quick intro to AJAX using vanilla js https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp. Depending on what your client looks like, you could do this with jQuery or any front-end framework

Comment: I am new to Spring framework. I thought there is an easy way that I can handle button clicks from my html in my java controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Your page has forms and buttons which makes requests to the server.

Spring handles the requests on the server-side.

If you're using Chrome, you can monitor the network behavior on the *Network* tab when you press the referred button to see the request and response between the browser and the server.

Comment: The javascript function contains a url. When the page calls the server, Spring Web finds the target method with RequestMapping.